# Transitions working in Chrome and Firefox, not in Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I used this code:

codepen.io/egrucza/pen/PwbzPy

It seems to work in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. I have added Modernizr, but that doesn't help me out. The triangles in Safari are visible without hovering and have an odd placement. The hover doesn't do anything.

Any quick fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's because you use `transform:: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);` which requires vendor prefix on Safari. Try to add:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0%);
```